# Javafx Css variable defination Error: Expected '<number>' while parsing 'font-size'

Tags: java, css, javafx

I get javaFx css parse error while defining new variables in css.

It perfectly runs ok with a given constant like: -fx-font-size: 10;

Here is the code:

```
.root {
    tab-label-text-size: 10;
}
.label {
    -fx-font-size: tab-label-text-size;
}
```

Whatever I tried, I couldnt get rid of this exception.
I also used other variables like this and they also run ok.

**Expected '' while parsing '-fx-font-size' at [9,19]**

Maybe a bug in javaFx??

Comment: This is not working only with colors.

Comment: Specifying your own properties works for colors only. You may be able to use the fact that the `-fx-font-size` property is inherited by default to your advantage tough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JavaFX CSS you can assign a color constant:

```
* {
    -color : #f44242;
}

.button {
    -fx-text-fill: -color;
}
```

**But unfortunately, font size constants are not supported by the CssParser**